# How to use onbeforeunload event handler without the pop up message?

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

I am trying to use onbeforeunload event to log some finalized log of the page (I cannot do it in the middle of the visit, because I have to get the log right before user leaves).

```
function handleBeforeUnload(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.returnValue = '';

    // make some log
    logSomeFinalizedInfo();

    return null;
}
```

However, on Android phone, this pops up a message "Are you sure you want to leave", which is not expected, how can I use this event handler without having this message pop up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution, which is to remove the handler after use (**removeEventListener**):

```
function handleBeforeUnload(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.returnValue = '';

    // make some log
    logSomeFinalizedInfo();

    removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please consider using the `Beacon API` which is specifically meant for this purpose. 
More on it here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API

> Not only do these techniques represent poor coding patterns, some of them are unreliable and result in the perception of poor page load performance for the next navigation. The Beacon API provides a standard way to address these issues.

Comment: This is too heavy. We wanted something very simple

Comment: @RainCast: The single call to the built-in `navigator.sendBeacon(url, data)` is too heavy?

Comment: @Ry- by heavy I mean it is not a well supported API, https://caniuse.com/#search=Beacon There is no support for IE at all.

Comment: IE is not a supported browser on the planet and adopting IE is equivalent to adopting insecurities.

Comment: @RainCast - IE is not a supported browser on the planet and adopting IE is equivalent to adopting insecurities - https://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-security-chief-ie-is-not-a-browser-so-stop-using-it-as-your-default/

Comment: @CodeWalker well, no matter what, IE is an important browser, and a large percentage of our customers use IE. We support our customers' choice. I don't have any bias against any brands. IE is important, and IE has customers for a reason.